# Hex Converter ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, exception

My Hex Converter is working fine when converting valid hex but its giving me an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` error when converting invalid hex and I don't know how to handle this exception.

My Code:

```
public string DecryptHex(ref string Data)
{
    string Data1 = "";
    string inData = "";
    while (Data.Length > 0)
    {
        Data1 = System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(Data.Substring(0, 2), 16)).ToString();
        inData = inData + Data1;
        Data = Data.Substring(2, Data.Length - 2);
    }
    return inData;
}
```

Comment: Well, if you are giving it invalid hex values, what exactly do you expect it to do, if not throw an exception?

Comment: You could use a regular expression to check whether your data is valid.

Comment: Why convert it first to uint32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex to check whether your data is valid:

```
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Data, "0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+")) {
}
```

--

```
public string DecryptHex(ref string Data)
{
    string inData = string.Empty;
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Data, "0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+")) {
        string Data1 = "";
        while (Data.Length > 0)
        {
            Data1 = System.Convert.ToChar(System.Convert.ToUInt32(Data.Substring(0, 2), 16)).ToString();
            inData = inData + Data1;
            Data = Data.Substring(2, Data.Length - 2);
        }
    }
    return inData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want your method to return if it doesn´t receive a valid hexadecimal number but you might want to test your string if it is a valid hex number with the following regular expression:

```
Regex.IsMatch(test, @"\A\b[0-9a-fA-F]+\b\Z");
```

Although, I would suggest that you leave it as it is and let your method throw an exception if the argument is wrong. You should have error handling on a higher level to recover from this.